# how to make global variable and print outside function

Tags: angularjs, restangular

I am using AngularJS & RESTangular. 
Is it possible to print or get return from function from below code?

This is my controller code

```
var items = $scope.items = [] 
Restangular.all("items").getList().then(function(serverItems) {
    items = serverItems;
    $scope.items = serverItems
});

// PRINTING ITEMS HERE IN CONSOLE
console.log(items);
console.log(serverItems);

}
```

Comment: Put the console.log inside the Restangular function

Comment: no that's not I want.. I want once restangular complete with response, items get populated with response and I can past this items to another function or do manipulation to items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call the function by passing the `$scope.items`.

```
var items = $scope.items = [];
Restangular.all("items").getList().then(function(serverItems) {
    items = serverItems;
    $scope.items = serverItems;

    // successful getting response from the server, now print or manipulate the data
    printItems(items);
});

// PRINTING ITEMS HERE IN CONSOLE
function printItems(items) {
    console.log(items);
    // do data manipulation
}
```

In this case, you will wait for getting the response, and then do the data manipulation on the response data.

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
var items = $scope.items = [];
Restangular.all("items").getList().then(function(serverItems) {
    items = serverItems;
    $scope.items = serverItems;
    // PRINTING ITEMS HERE IN CONSOLE
    console.log(items);
    console.log(serverItems);
});
```

You can't use those variables outside their function. You have to use them inside it. You can use them in HTML too using `{{items}}`

Comment: how to handle .. suppose if some other function depend on items values?